# JAVAFX ListView - Is it possible to hide an ID 'column', or should I use a single column TableView?

Tags: listview, javafx

In MS Access a 'ListBox' can hide the first 'column' of a 2 column ResultSet - it's great for hiding 'IDs' which are easily accessible when the user selects an item from the list.

If possible I want to do the same in JavaFX with a ListView so I can populate a second ListView based on the selection from the first ListView.

This is how I populate the ListView :
`menuList1.setItems(MenuUtilities.getDivisions());`
from

```
public static ObservableList getDivisions() {

    ObservableList divisionListRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        Connection conn;
        conn = Connect_db.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT ID, Division FROM tbl_ref_employee_divisions";
        PreparedStatement prestate = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet divsResult = prestate.executeQuery();
        while (divsResult.next()) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= divsResult.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                divisionListRow.add(divsResult.getString(i));
            }
        }
        prestate.close();
        divsResult.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return divisionListRow;
}
```

the listview displays :
[see image of List View Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMqV6.jpg)

From the image I get the impression a listView cannot format an array.
If so, am I better using a single column TableView?
And if so how do I display one string column from the ObservableList and access the integer ID of the selected item in code.

many thanks

Comment: ..perhaps I should read my ResultSet into a 2 field class and pass one field (as a single String type) to the ObservableList..but it still begs the question - using best practice - how do I get to my ID? Clearly I'm a noob..

Comment: ..I have a not-elegant solution which is to use the list view, populate with 'Division' only (no duplicates) and just use the selected Division as a parameter back to the dbase to get the id...yuk but it will do until I learn a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the `ResultSet` in a way that for each row you add an element for each of the columns. You need to add a single item for each row you want to display in the `ListView`, i.e. in this case a single item per row in the `ResultSet`.

Since you want the `ID` to be accessible, you should create a custom type containing the values for both rows (or use an existing class like `Pair`) and use a `cellFactory` to choose the data to display.

```
public class EmployeeDivision {
    private final long id; // or maybe String/int as type?
    private final String name;

    public EmployeeDivision (long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /* getters */

}
```

```
ListView<EmployeeDivision> menuList1;
```

```
menuList1.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<EmployeeDivision>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(EmployeeDivision item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty || item == null ? "" : item.getName());
    }
});
```

```
while (divsResult.next()) {
    divisionListRow.add(new EmployeeDivision(divsResult.getLong(1), divsResult.getString(2)));
}
```

This allows you to access the id of the selected item like this:

```
EmployeeDivision selectedItem = menuList1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if (selectedItem != null) {
    System.out.println("id = " + selectedItem.getId());
} else {
    System.out.println("no item selected");
}
```

BTW: I recommend specifying type parameters unless you've got a really good reason to use the raw type. This allows the compiler to do some checks that could result in issues that are hard to spot, if the raw type was used.

Comment: Thanks fabian that's a lot to digest. I must confess up until now cell factory seemed daunting and I've been avoiding it. But with your advice I feel confident my research will be worthwhile. Coming from MS Access and VBA the learning curve is very steep..but every win is sweet. Many, many thanks to you and all the people who contribute on these places. (unfortunately I'm too new to vote.)

Comment: @RodWenban If this works for you, you could still accept the answer.

Comment: May I ask, can you explain further about specifying type parameters? I know what a type is, but I don't know what you mean in this context..

Comment: @RodWenban Instead of `ObservableList` use `ObservableList<EmployeeDivision>` in the return type/declarations. This allows the compiler to check that you don't accidentally adding the wrong object type. Using the raw type `ObservableList`, you could add `String`s without the compiler complaining. If you later retrieve such an element from the list expecting it to be of type `EmployeeDivision`, a cast would yield a `ClassCastException`. It may not be easy to find out where you add the wrong kind of object. It's best to allow the compiler to do some checks, even if the declarations become longer

Comment: tks I've done that. almost there..2 things what 'type' is `divisionListRow`? Also, to populate the employee divison object I'm using a Utilities class with a static void method. In a few words is that reasonable or should I use another approach. It seems to me to keep things modular or cleaner?

Comment: I think I have solved it but I'm not getting any data in my ListView..how can I paste 30 lines of code..do I need a new question? Once I have resolved this I am going to study every line until I understand it thoroughly.

Comment: A `static` method is fine, but using non-static methods may be desirable (strategy pattern if you've got scenes filled with data in similar ways). Also it could be beneficial to create an object managing the lifecycle of the `Connection` and reuing it/managing authentification...

Comment: The while loop replaces the while loop in the `getDivisions` method and it's type as well as the return type should be changed to `ObservableList<EmployeeDivision>`. 30+ lines are impossible to deal with in comments.

Comment: Thankyou for your advice, yeh I have a connection object that I'm improving/tightening as I learn, and yes I have strategy that seems to keep things tidy and manageable. On your second comment, I have fixed that and now have the result I required all along thanks to you and to @GreenZebra. This is a model I use alot between 'forms' it's so good to have that behind me at last. cheers again!